# golang, api de cep (iniciante)

Tags: golang

Este programa me retorna o endereço da pessoa pelo CEP fornecido. Eu digito o CEP na URL da minha API e ele volta o endereço em forma de STRUCT no meu terminal
Mas eu quero que o programa me de a opção de digitar o CEP no terminal e então voltar o endereço

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)



type CEP struct {
    CEP         string `json:"cep"`
    Logradouro  string `json:"logradouro"`
    Complemento string `json:"complemento"`
    Bairro      string `json:"bairro"`
    Cidade      string `json:"cidade"`
}

func main() {
    
    var dadosCEP CEP
    
    resposta, _ := http.Get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/72220064/json/")

    
    dados, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resposta.Body)

    
    json.Unmarshal(dados, &dadosCEP)

    
    fmt.Println(dadosCEP)

}
```

Comment: Veja se o pacote [`bufio`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio) o ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

A própria lib `fmt` tem uma função para ler uma entrada do terminal.

seu código ficaria assim:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type CEP struct {
    CEP         string `json:"cep"`
    Logradouro  string `json:"logradouro"`
    Complemento string `json:"complemento"`
    Bairro      string `json:"bairro"`
    Cidade      string `json:"cidade"`
}

func main() {

    var dadosCEP CEP
    var cep string
    fmt.Println("Por favor entre com o CEP desejado:")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &cep)

    resposta, _ := http.Get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/")

    dados, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resposta.Body)
    defer resposta.Body.Close()

    json.Unmarshal(dados, &dadosCEP)

    fmt.Println(dadosCEP)

}
```

Comment: deu certinho cara, muito obrigado de verdade